# How to handle Response JSON have custom field with out key?

Tags: go

Query Api and response a custom JSON, how to Unmarshal it. the sample JSON:

```
{"14AcKEr19gHJvgwQhK7sfFm6YJGmoZZoqu": {
"final_balance": 61914248289,
"n_tx": 3472,
"total_received": 3479994002972
}}
```

The key is a hex string. So how to handle it with golang convention, anyone can help me?

Below is my try test code:

```
c.OnResponse(func(r *colly.Response) {
    jsonData := r.Body

    fmt.Println(string(jsonData))
    fmt.Println("==================")

    //parse bitcoin json
    jsonMap := make(map[string]interface{})
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &jsonMap)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(jsonMap)

    dumpMap("", jsonMap)
})

func dumpMap(space string, m map[string]interface{}) {
    for k, v := range m {
        if mv, ok := v.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
            fmt.Printf("{ \"%v\": \n", k)
            dumpMap(space+"\t", mv)
            fmt.Printf("}\n")
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%v %v : %v\n", space, k, v)
        }
    }
}
```

and go run `cmd/main.go`, the console is print here:

```
{"14AcKEr19gHJvgwQhK7sfFm6YJGmoZZoqu": {
    "final_balance": 75494521080,
    "n_tx": 3493,
    "total_received": 3493574275763
}}
==================
map[14AcKEr19gHJvgwQhK7sfFm6YJGmoZZoqu:map[n_tx:3493 total_received:3.493574275763e+12 final_balance:7.549452108e+10]]
{ "14AcKEr19gHJvgwQhK7sfFm6YJGmoZZoqu":
         final_balance : 7.549452108e+10
         n_tx : 3493
         total_received : 3.493574275763e+12
}
```

Do I need customised `unmarshal func` to get string key? If I use `14AcKEr19gHJvgwQhK7sfFm6YJGmoZZoqu` as key I can't easily to access. I just want to know how handle it.

Comment: Just unmarshall to a interface. And format/handle it from there.

Comment: @majidarif i just update the question and add more backgroud concerns to this question. welcome give some advise.

Comment: There is no point in trying to unmarshall this directly to a struct because the key could and does start with a number. Unmarshall it to a string map with the value as an object of struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can unmarshal it into map, so you can get generated key as a key of map
https://play.golang.org/p/IfEjjvKakpu

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

var input = `{"14AcKEr19gHJvgwQhK7sfFm6YJGmoZZoqu": {
"final_balance": 61914248289,
"n_tx": 3472,
"total_received": 3479994002972
}}`

type object struct {
    FinalBalance uint64 `json:"final_balance"`
    NTX uint64 `json:"n_tx"`
    TotalReceived uint64 `json:"total_received"`
}

func main() {
    var result map[string]object;
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &result);
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("result: %+v", result)
    // result: map[14AcKEr19gHJvgwQhK7sfFm6YJGmoZZoqu:{FinalBalance:61914248289 NTX:3472 TotalReceived:3479994002972}]
}
```